# Is it correct: I had been staying , in my situation?

Tags: past-tense, perfect-aspect

Is this correct:

> I **had been staying** in the Emergency Department for three days until the doctors **could** identify the missing diagnosis.

where "staying" is used together with another action from the past?

Answer (score 0):

It's not wrong, but your context doesn't yet mean that you need to use the past perfect.  It would also be correct to say.

> I stayed in the Emergency Department for three days until the doctors could identify the missing diagnosis.

This is a short narrative.  There is a sequence of events that happened in the past and they occur in time order. You are talking about the time when you stayed in the emergency department.  You don't need the past perfect just because one event occurred before another event.

You use the past perfect when you are describing a past time, and you want to mention an event that occurred prior to the time you are talking about.

> I was in the hospital when I got my diagnois (I'm talking about the time when I got my diagnosis).  I was in a bed in the emergency department and I had been there for three days. (past perfect. This is in the time before the time when I got my diagnosis.)

The past perfect is the rarest tense.  Don't over use it.

Comment: I really understand your very good explanation, Many thanks for your help.